# Split Index Results Over Several Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to generate a list of all the characters in my Character table, but split them so that the page isn't extremely long. I'd like for the default to be 15 characters, then you'll be presented with a "Next" button, to view the next 15 results. Is this possible to do in rails?

Here is a copy of my index.html.erb (I've taken out all the .CSS information):

```
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Race</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Class</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Alignment</strong></th>
        </tr>
    <% @characters.each do |character| %>
        <% if character.user_id == current_user.id %>
            <tr onclick="location.href= '<%= character_path(id: "#{character.id}") %>'">
                <td><%= character.name%></td>
                <td><%= character.race %></td>
                <td><%= character.class_ %></td>
                <td><%= character.alignment %></td>
            </tr>
        <% else %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= character.name%></td>
                <td><%= character.race %></td>
                <td><%= character.class_ %></td>
                <td><%= character.alignment %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

If need be, I am open to using JavaScript or Jquery to get this done.

Comment: check out `kaminari` gem it is built for pagging

Comment: https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is called **pagination**. There are many ways to do it, but the [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem is the most popular. Here's a guide to using it in your Rails app: http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari

In short, your controller should be responsible for setting `@characters` to only the particular page you want to return (with Kaminari, that's `@characters = Character.page(params[:page].to_i)`). Then, provide links on your view to go to the previous and next pages (making sure to handle the first and last page properly).